# How to make an element inside a div stop having a specific class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap to make a div that has the class="text-center" how can i make a p tag that lives inside the div not have the class text-center? 
code:

```
<div id="div1" class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
<h3><a id="what"  class="margin">What Am I?</h3></a>
<img  src="(img url)"  class="img-responsive img-circle margin"
style="display:inline" alt="Me" width="350" height="650">
<h3 >I'm A Young Freelancer.</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: your `p` tag is not actually going to have the class of `text-center` but having the container or div with `text-center` class will make that `p` tag respect the CSS rule if you want the `p` tag not going to respect this CSS rule, do some inline CSS on your `p` tag or with a CSS rule of `!important` to prevent the `text-center` rule. If i understand this wrong, edit your post and be specific

Comment: Please provide actual code. Also, do you want all `<p>` elements within that div type not to have that class, or just that particular element? Finally, is it just the centering of text that you're trying to avoid?

Comment: I just edited the code. The class that i am trying to avoid is text-center for the <h3> tags

Answer (score 0):

Mate, apply this concept:

Use text center class only on text blocks. 
Set a block centered horizontaly by width inheritance on structure blocks.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block-center"><p class="centered">HI</p>  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.container {
  width:100%;
}

.block-center {
  color:white;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:#0c0c0c;
  width:100px;
}
.centered {
  text-align:center;
```

To center a text (horizontal) you use text-align:center;
To center a block (horizontal) you use margin: 0 auto;

I recommend you check [this](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#block)

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: that's nice. And as he is using bootstrap he can use the .center-block class too.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix this `<h3><a id="what"  class="margin">What Am I?</h3></a>` to `<h3><a id="what"  class="margin">What Am I?</a></h3>`.

Second, you should change your concept. The only child of your `#div1` that's not an `H3` is your `IMG`. You don't want to align your `H3` with `text-center` but want to align your image, right? Then you shouldn't use `.text-center` on `#div1`, maybe an `.center-block` directly on your `img` would solve your case.

If that's not your case (and your `#div1` have other children) then you should make exceptions on your CSS. As your `H3` doesn't have anything saying what's your text alignment, it'll get the parent property (in this case, `center`). If you just make an specific rule to your case then your problem is over.

```
#div1 > h3 {
    text-align: justify; /* or whatever you want to */
}
```